Why Car Parrinello Molecular Dynamics doesn't need an SCF calculation at every time-step?
Reading the various terms of the Lagrangian in CP-MD I'm trying to understand why there is not an SCF procedure hidden there.
In fact, it seems to me like the second term of the Eulero-Lagrange equation is similar (except for the variational minimization) to that of Born-Oppenheimer Molecular Dynamics, also if it is placed equal to the "force" due to the fictitious mass.
I'm missing this essential and maybe obvious feature to appreciate this method.
I'm sorry for not writing the equations.
Many thanks

The Matter Modeling SE might be a good place to ask this.

@JonCuster The same question was asked in Matter Modeling SE  and in Physics SE  ( https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/821944/why-doesnt-car-parrinello-molecular-dynamics-require-an-scf-calculation/ ), where an answer was obtained.
